# car on cons gets nil

Tags: debugging, association-lists

I define an alist like this:

```
 (setq major-mode-list
  '(((emacs-lisp-mode inferior-emacs-lisp-mode) . ("Elisp" "Emacs"))
    ((haskell-mode) . ("Haskell" "Haskell"))
    ))
```

And match current major-mode with this function:

```lisp
 (defun major-mode-icon-3 ()
   (let* ((match (assoc
                  (car (mapcar
                        (lambda (element)
                          (member (buffer-local-value 'major-mode (current-buffer))
                                  element))
                        (map-keys major-mode-list)))
                  major-mode-list))
          (name (car (cdr match)))
          (icon (car (cdr (cdr match)))))
     )
   )
```

Function works correct in `((emacs-lisp-mode inferior-emacs-lisp-mode) . ("Elisp" "Emacs"))`.

But not correct in `((haskell-mode) . ("Haskell" "Haskell"))`. The function will
return `nil` because of `(car (haskell-mode))`.

Question: How to correct this function?

Comment: I urge you to run the function under `edebug` (evaluate the `defun` using `C-u C-M-x` instead of `C-M-x`). This will let you step through the function and evaluate individual expressions.

Comment: `(buffer-local-value 'major-mode (current-buffer))` is redundant, just use `major-mode` instead.

Comment: You're constantly using `assoc` on the result of the `member` call of the first element of the key-list.

Comment: @politza Because I need to literate over matched items in the alist.

Comment: Try `cl-assoc-if`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two methods.
One simple methods is `(remove nil '(nil nil (clojure-mode) nil nil ..)`. This answer is from IRC channel #emacs.

And another method is to use `cl-some` which is from Google search:

```
 (cl-some
    (lambda (elem)
      (when (not (null elem))
        elem))
    (mapcar
     (lambda (element)
       (member major-mode element))
     (map-keys major-mode-list)))
```

Better way is use `cl-assoc-if` as @npostavs suggest.